# Excerpt post wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, funções

O que está errado? Fiz a função para dar excerpt nos posts do wordpress e importar para outro site, porém ele não está cortando com o que eu defini.

Alguém pode dar uma luz?

```
<?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="moldG">
                        <div class="thumbsG">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail( array(300,266) ); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wptexto">
                            <a class="blog" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            <?php the_excerpt(); 
                             if ( is_category() || is_archive() ) {
                                    the_excerpt();
                                    } 
                           function new_excerpt_length($length) {
                               return 240;
                               }
            endwhile; ?>
                    </div>  
                </div>
```

Comment: Não tem a ver com sua pergunta, mas você está chamando the_excerpt duas vezes na página de categoria e de arquivo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é assim que se usa este filtro. Primeiro você deve declarar a função `new_excerpt_length` no `functions.php` do seu tema e então adicionar como filtro de `excerpt_length`.

```
function new_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 240;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length');
```

Depois disso o tamanho do resumo retornado por `the_excerpt()` será de no máximo 240 palavras em todo o site.

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui.